# Product of an open set and an element of a topological group, in a transformation group, is again an open set.

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, group-theory, topological-groups

Suppose that $X$ is a topological space, and $T$ is a topological group which continuously acts on $X$ on the right. We call the pair $(X,T)$ a (right) transformation group.
Now suppose that $\equiv$ is an “invariant” equivalence relation on $X$ in the sense that $x.t\equiv y.t$ whenever $x\equiv y$ for all $t\in T$ and for all $x,y\in X$.
Now consider the quotient topology on $X/\equiv$ and let $G$ be an open set in $X/\equiv$. Does it follow that the set $\bigcup_{[x]\in G} [x.t]$ is open in $X$ for any $t\in T$?

Comment: Not great to call $G$ an open subset of a space with a group action... but anyway the union $U_t$ as you describe is, for $t=1$, the inverse image of $G$ by the projection $X\to X/\equiv$, which is continuous by definition of the quotient topology, so the inverse image $U_1$ is open. And $U_t=U_1t$, so it's open just because $T$ acts by self-homeomorphisms.

Comment: thanks, I ignored these homeomorphisms @YCor

Comment: So $\equiv$ on $X$ is defined by $\forall t \in T: x\cdot t = y \cdot t$, if I understand correctly.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma no, our equivalence relation is an arbitrary one such that it is also invariant as defined above.

Comment: So you have an equivalence relation that preserves the action: $\forall x,y: x \equiv y \implies \forall t: x \cdot t \equiv y \cdot t$ so the action can be defined on $X/{\equiv}$ as well?